# what does this highlighting of folders refers too

Tags: windows-8, ntfs

have a look at the below screen cut which i have taken from my windows 8 :

[image]

its one of the physical drive with ntfs format, could anyone explain the mystery beyond the folder name's(file name's) were highlighted.i have checked other folders which are normal 
[image]

both of the drives were with ntfs format under windows 8 ,what makes the folder and files names for highlighted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blue font means that folder has been compresses. Windows may compress rarely used files to save space at the cost of performance. If it bothers you, you can disable highlighting in *Folder Options* → *View* tab → uncheck *Show encrypted or compresses NTFS files in color*.

[image: Screenshot of Folder Options window with highlighting checkbox underlined]

Compression can be disabled for specific files by opening their *Properties* → *Advanced*.

There's also green coloring for encrypted files.

Comment: "at the cost of performance" is not true in most szenarios on modern PC. As the CPUs are much faster these days and has "cores doing nothing" very often the time save readin less data from the disk is higher then the time needed to uncompress. Tests showing that in many cases compressing the windows and/or program files folder actualy speed up the system (not much, but measurable)...

Comment: @chrfin I guess those tests you mention give such results because HDD speed is the limiting factor, so decreasing file size improves performance. That probably won't be the case for SSD drives.

Comment: It actually was a test if it makes sense to compress that two folders on SSDs to save space as SSD space is expensive and even there it was marginaly faster WITH compression - I was suprised myself...

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for this can be, that the folders are using NTFS compression:
[image]